# No viable overloaded '-=' after redefining operators

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to define "-=" and "-" for a class that represents vector in 2D but I get this error:

Vecteur2D.cc:131:7: error: no viable overloaded '-='
vec1-=vec2;

```
Vecteur2D.cc:81:23: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has
    type 'const Vecteur2D', but method is not marked const
Vecteur2D& Vecteur2D::operator -= (const Vecteur2D& vec){


here is my code for the two operator: 

Vecteur2D& Vecteur2D::operator -= (const Vecteur2D& vec){
  x_=x_-vec.x_;
  y_=y_-vec.y_;
  return *this;
  }

and: 


const Vecteur2D operator +(const Vecteur2D& vec1, const Vecteur2D& vec2){
vec1+=vec2;
return vec1;
}
```

Comment: well `vec1+=vec2;` => vec1 is passed a const and you are trying to modify it.

Comment: the error about `operator-=` is in code you didnt post, though your `operator+` has similar problem. You declared `vec1` as `const` but try to modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a non-const method on a `const` instance. Your `operator-=` looks ok, but if you try to call it eg like this:

```
const Vecteur2D x,y;
x -= y;               // error
```

You get an error similar to the one you report. `-=` is expected to modify the left operand and your `operator-=` does that. The left operand cannot be `const`.

Your `operator+=` has issues with const correctness as well:

```
const Vecteur2D operator +(const Vecteur2D& vec1, const Vecteur2D& vec2){
vec1+=vec2;
return vec1;
}
```

You cannot modify `vec1` because it is `const`. `operator+` is expected to *not* modify its operands and return a new instance. Your `operator+` is *not* doing that. Assuming you have a correct `+=` the `operator+` can be written as:

```
Vecteur2D operator +(const Vecteur2D& vec1, const Vecteur2D& vec2){
    Vecteur2D result = vec1;  // non const copy
    result += vec2;
    return result;
}
```

For more details I refer you to [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

(PS: As far as I know, previously it was considered good practice to return `const` values, though it prevents move semantics and is no longer recommended)

Comment: Another way to get a copy to do `+=` on and return is to make the first argument a plain `Vecteur2D` without const or reference and then use it for the add-assign and return value.